# How to save SVG in Inkscape with viewBox?

Tags: svg, inkscape, viewbox

How to save SVG file in Inkscape with viewbox parameter?

In SVG file with width="50" height="62.5"
should be this: viewBox="0 0 50 62.5"

QGIS can not use SVG without viewBox correctly.

Comment: You have to open the XML editor (Edit menu), choose the `<svg>` element and add the viewBox by hand.

Comment: Current Inkscape versions add a viewbox by default. Probably you just need to update.

Comment: And if you are using an older version of Inkscape, select "Optimized SVG" when you save. There is an option to add a viewBox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm here because of a similar issue, so something for future problem solvers...
As of October 2022 Inkscape still has core problems with size/viewbox values in the XML.

**Inkscape is funky at true-scaling of objects** - confusing Size, Viewbox and scaled vector data and from the looks of it visually imitates resizing in the editor. Check your XML code - if stroke .02 becomes weird .001343, your size and viewBox are not 1 to 1 and Inkscape generated viewbox code might produce unexpected results when the SVG is stretched to the expected size.

**Check Document Properties** - if *Scale* comes with commas, such as 3.779528, something has happened along the way. Change it down to 1 and rescale the original viewboxed object to fit the document scale. Your Size and Viewbox should now be the same and modern Inscape writes that code into Plain SVG's XML.